# How can I add use javascript function to generate a signature for my karate tests?

Tags: javascript, karate

So we want to run our api testing including a signature we will generate through use of a js library.

This should be done in two parts, as we need to make an external call to get the private key for signing, and then each url being tested should get it's own unique signature.

My attempt to do this so far, is to add a function to the output of the `karate-config.js`.  Currently I am only testing this with a dummy function, but the plan would be to seed the private key into the function and then have it called for each test.

```
  var config = {
    env: env,
    base_url: karate.properties['test.base_url'],
    utils: {}
  }

  config.utils.getSignature=function(something){
    return 'signature'
  }
```

Unfortunately this is where I am getting stopped, when I put the following in my feature file:

```
    Scenario Outline: Location
      * url base_url
      * print utils
      * print utils.getSignature
      * def signature = utils.getSignature('wassup')
      * print signature
```

Then I get:

```
16:34:49.501 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] {
  "getSignature": "#function"
}
16:34:49.507 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] #function
...
failed features:
location.location: [2.1:85] location.feature:70 - javascript evaluation failed: utils.getSignature('wassup'), TypeError: utils.getSignature is not a function in <eval> at line number 1
```

Note: If I use read() to get a js function from a file that does work if that is relevant.

How do I create a function I can use in the karate config file?

Note: Probably every test will need to run this so it makes sense doing it in config.

Comment: that should have worked as expected, no idea. if really stuck follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - you can see existing unit tests for reference: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/core/parallel/karate-config.js - if you are a java shop, my recommendation is to use a static method, which you can call from any feature